# How can I see complete package name in dpkg -l

Tags: gnome-terminal

After typing `dpkg -l` all packages are listed, but some package names are not complete `google-chrome-stable` in this case.
Can I see the complete package name? Although I can prevent this happening by maximizing terminal window before typing dpkg -l.

[image]

Comment: What a discovery - the contents of the terminal [depends on its size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dpkg` optimizes its output for your terminal width by narrowing the columns of the output table, as you see, to avoid long lines wrapping.

You can simply prevent this by piping its output through e.g. `cat`, which does nothing on itself (just copying its input to its output), but disconnects `dpkg`'s output from the terminal, so that it can't know its width and will not optimize anything:

```
dpkg -l | cat
```

Of course the same disconnection takes place if you pipe it into anything else for further processing anyway, no need to additionally use `cat` as part of a longer pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

`dpkg -l` optimizes its output for your terminal width. So lie to `dpkg -l` about the width.

```
env COLUMNS=500 dpkg -l
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dpkg-query`, which provides explicit control over the output format including a field width specification.

Ex. to print the package name in a fieldwidth of 50 columns followed by the package version:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package;-50}\t${Version}\n'
```

or (if you only need the full package name)

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package}\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
apt list --installed
```

instead.